# Open Refine multiple word classification

Tags: json, openrefine, grel

I have a project with keywords in Google Refine.

I need to select multiple keywords from the project and move them to a specific category.

For example:

I have a list with multiple keywords: car, sports car, luxury car, blue car...

I want to collectively classify all these keywords under the category "Cars".

Until now, I have done this by searching for the keyword via the text filter and then categorizing it via the edit cells -> transform function. But I want to select multiple keywords at once.

Answer (score 1):

With the Text Filter, you can add more than one keyword (click on the « include » link to add more), and then your Transform operation will apply to all rows displayed.

[image]

Regards, Antoine